# Bigcommerce Edit PayPal Button & Extend Link Area

Tags: html, paypal, bigcommerce

We are using PayPal Express to quick checkout on the cart level. We would like to add "another" button that says PayPal Credit but has the same target with the original PayPal Express button. Extending clickable area of the first button would resolve the issue. Or could it be possible to make the 2nd button have the same target?

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
lang.InvalidQuantity = "%%LNG_InvalidQuantity%%";
lang.Calculating = "%%LNG_Calculating%%"
lang.CalculateShipping = "%%LNG_CalculateShipping%%"
lang.ChooseShippingMethod = "%%LNG_ChooseShippingMethod%%"
lang.CartRemoveConfirm = '%%LNG_CartRemoveConfirm%%';
lang.ConfirmRemoveGiftWrapping = '%%LNG_ConfirmRemoveGiftWrapping%%';
lang.SelectCountry = '%%LNG_ChooseShippingCountry%%';
lang.SelectState = '%%LNG_ChooseShippingState%%';
lang.EnterZip = '%%LNG_EnterShippingZip%%';
</script>
<script src="%%GLOBAL_CdnAppPath%%/javascript/jquery/plugins/imodal/imodal.js?%%GLOBAL_JSCacheToken%%" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="Block Moveable Panel" id="CartContent_modified">
    <div class="BlockContent">
        <div style="display: %%GLOBAL_HideShoppingCartGrid%%" id="CartFormContainer">
            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return Cart.ValidateQuantityForm(this);" action="/cart.php" name="cartForm" id="cartForm" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" />
            <table class="CartContents Stylize General" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="HL-CartItems" colspan="2">%%LNG_CartItems%%</th>
                        <th class="HL-Qty">%%LNG_Qty%%</th>
                        <th class="HL-Remove">&nbsp;</th>
                        <th class="HL-ItemPrice">%%LNG_ItemPrice%%</th>
                        <th class="HL-Total">%%LNG_HC_total%%</th>                        
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr class="SubTotal">
                        <td colspan="6"><div>%%LNG_Subtotal%% <em class="ProductPrice">%%GLOBAL_CartItemTotal%%</em></div></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="SubTotal" style="%%GLOBAL_HideGiftWrappingTotal%%">
                        <td colspan="6"><div>%%LNG_GiftWrapping%% <em class="ProductPrice">%%GLOBAL_GiftWrappingTotal%%</em></div></td>
                      
                    </tr>
                    %%SNIPPET_NormalCoupons%%
                    <tr class="SubTotal" style="%%GLOBAL_HideDiscountAmount%%">
                        <td colspan="6"><div>%%LNG_Discount%% <em class="ProductPrice">%%GLOBAL_DiscountAmount%%</em></div></td>
                       
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="SubTotal" style="display:none;">
                        <td colspan="6" class="HL-ShoppingCartShippingEstimator">
                            <div>
                            <a href="#" class="EstimateShippingLink" onclick="Cart.ToggleShippingEstimation(); return false;"><em>%%LNG_CalculateShippingHandling%%</em></a>
                            <div class="EstimateShipping" style="display: none;">
        <div class="EstimatedShippingMethods" style="display: none;">
                                    <div class="ShippingMethodList">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <dl class="hideThis">
                                    <dt><span class="Required">*</span>&nbsp;%%LNG_Country%%:</dt>
                                    <dd>
                                        <select name="shippingZoneCountry" id="shippingZoneCountry" onchange="Cart.ToggleShippingEstimateCountry();">
                                            %%GLOBAL_ShippingCountryList%%
                                        </select>
                                    </dd>

                                    <dt><span class="Required" id="shippingZoneStateRequired">*</span>&nbsp;%%LNG_StateProvince%%:</dt>
                                    <dd>
                                        <select style="display: %%GLOBAL_ShippingHideStateList%%" name="shippingZoneState" id="shippingZoneState">
                                            %%GLOBAL_ShippingStateList%%
                                        </select>
                                        <input style="display: %%GLOBAL_ShippingHideStateBox%%" type="text" class="Textbox" name="shippingZoneStateName" id="shippingZoneStateName" value="%%GLOBAL_AddressState%%" />
                                    </dd>

                                    <dt><span class="Required">*</span>&nbsp;%%LNG_ZipPostcode%%:</dt>
                                    <dd><input type="text" class="Textbox" name="shippingZoneZip" id="shippingZoneZip" value="%%GLOBAL_ShippingZip%%" /></dd>
                                    <!--dd class="Submit EstimateShippingButtons">
                                        <input type="button" onclick="Cart.EstimateShipping();" value="%%LNG_CalculateShipping%%" class="btn alt" />
                                       
                                        <div><a href="#" onclick="ToggleShippingEstimation2(); return false;" class="txt-link btn">%%LNG_Cancel%%</a></div>
                                    </dd-->
                                </dl>
        <p class="Submit EstimateShippingButtons">
                                    <span><a href="#" onclick="Cart.ToggleShippingEstimation();">%%LNG_Cancel%%</a> %%LNG_or%% </span><input type="button" onclick="Cart.EstimateShipping();" value="%%LNG_CalculateShipping%%" />
                                </p>

                                
                            </div>

                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="display:%%GLOBAL_HideShoppingCartShippingCost%%" class="SubTotal ShippingRow">
                        <td colspan="6"><div>%%LNG_Shipping%% (%%GLOBAL_ShippingProvider%%) <em class="ProductPrice">%%GLOBAL_ShippingCost%%</em></div></td>
                    </tr>
                    %%SNIPPET_FreeShippingCoupons%%
                    <tr  style="display: %%GLOBAL_HideShoppingCartHandlingCost%%" class="SubTotal">
                        <td colspan="6"><div>%%LNG_Handling%% <em class="ProductPrice">%%GLOBAL_HandlingCost%%</em></div></td>
                    </tr>
                    %%GLOBAL_Taxes%%
                    %%SNIPPET_GiftCertificates%%
                    <tr class="SubTotal gtotal">
                        <td colspan="6"><div>%%LNG_GrandTotal%% <em class="ProductPrice">%%GLOBAL_CartTotal%%</em></div></td>
                    </tr>
                    %%GLOBAL_InclusiveTaxes%%
                </tfoot>
                <tbody>
                    %%SNIPPET_CartItems%%
                </tbody>
            </table>
             <div class="KeepShopping">
                <a href="javascript:history.go(-1);" class="btn">Continue shopping</a>
            </div>
            <div class="updateCart">
                <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Update Cart" title="%%LNG_Update%%" />
            </div>
            </form>


            <div class="ProceedToCheckout">
            <!--div class="CheckoutButton" style="%%GLOBAL_HideCheckoutButton%%">
                <a class="btn" href="%%GLOBAL_CheckoutLink%%" onclick="" title="%%LNG_CheckoutButtonTitle%%">%%LNG_HC_proceedcheckout%%</a>
            </div-->

                <div class="CheckoutButton" style="%%GLOBAL_HideCheckoutButton%%">
                    <a href="%%GLOBAL_CheckoutLink%%" onclick="%%GLOBAL_OptimizerLinkFunction%%" title="%%LNG_CheckoutButtonTitle%%">
                    %%GLOBAL_CartCheckoutButtonOptimizerScriptTag%%
                    <img src="https://cdn2.bigcommerce.com/server5400/vpslo31z/templates/__custom/images/blue/checkout.gif" alt="" />
                    %%GLOBAL_CartCheckoutButtonOptimizerNoScriptTag%%
                    </a>
                </div>
           
           
             <div class="AlternativeCheckout" style="%%GLOBAL_HideMultipleAddressShipping%%">
<p class="PTB20"><span style="%%GLOBAL_HideMultipleAddressShippingOr%%">-- %%LNG_or%% --</span><a href="%%GLOBAL_ShopPath%%/checkout.php?action=multiple"><strong>%%LNG_CheckoutWithMultipleAddresses%%</strong></a></p>
            </div>
                 %%GLOBAL_AdditionalCheckoutButtons%%
<div class="AlternativeCheckout">
<img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/i/buttons/ppcredit_MD_BNPOT_1x.png" alt="PayPal Credit" /> </div>
        </div>

       
        <div class="clear"></div>

        </div>


        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div style="display: %%GLOBAL_HideShoppingCartEmptyMessage%%">
            <p class="InfoMessage">
                %%LNG_NoItemsInCart%%
            </p>
            %%LNG_EmptyCartInfo%%
            <br>
            <a href="javascript:history.go(-1);">%%LNG_ContinueShopping%%</a> %%LNG_OnThe%% %%GLOBAL_StoreName%% %%LNG_EmptyHomePage%%
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (location.pathname !== '/checkout.php'){
    $('.EstimateShippingLink').click();
    $('#shippingZoneCountry').val(226);
 $('#shippingZoneState').val(51);
 $('#shippingZoneZip').val(19132);
 /*
 $('#shippingZoneCountry').change(function() {
  $('#shippingZoneState').val(51);
  $('#shippingZoneState').change(function(){
   $('#shippingZoneZip').val(19132);
  });
 });*/
    $('.Submit.EstimateShippingButtons > input').click();
    $('.hideThis').hide();
    $('.Submit.EstimateShippingButtons').hide();
}
$(document).ready(function(){
 //var labelForFixedShipping= $("div.shippingquote label").filter(function() { return ($(this).text().trim() === "Fixed Shipping") });
 //$("#shippingLabel").text($("#shippingLabel").text().replace("Fixed Shipping", "Your Shipping Cost"));
//alert($('#shippingLabel').html());
 //alert(labelForFixedShipping);
 //alert("Text");
 //alert(labelForFixedShipping.text());
 //labelForFixedShipping.text("Your Shipping Cost");
 
 var ht = $("label[for = shippingLabel]").text();
 //alert(ht);
});

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    var cartSubtotal = parseFloat("%%GLOBAL_CartItemTotal%%".replace(/[$,]/g, ''));
    if (cartSubtotal > 50) {
        $("<a href='http:/yourdomain.com/cart.php?action=add&product_id=8122'></a>").click(); 
    }
});
</script>
<script>
if (location.pathname !== '/checkout.php'){
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
        sessionStorage.setItem('totals', $('table.CartContents>tfoot').html());
    });
}
</script>
```

[image: shopping cart]

Comment: Why shouldn't it be possible? Have you tried it?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry for being unclear, @Geshode, I actually couldn't seem to find out how to do it in practice, even though I can think of possible solutions. Could you provide any insight?

Comment: can I see your website?  its simple just copy the ordinal checkout button and paste it again into new PayPal image or text.

Comment: @R.K.Bhardwaj Absolutely, website is located at www.fleetsafety.com
The problem is I can't see the original button's location and it seems like I don't have access to the snippet that it's included.